# Fragments when updating to react 16.2.0 is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fragment

I update my react version to 16.2.0 and I use Fragment to wrap some components. So I write:

```
import React from 'react;
```

And the I write:

```
const CustomerSearch = () => (
 <React.Fragment>
        <Field
          id="lastname"
          name="lastname"
          floatingLabelText="ΕΠΩΝΥΜΟ"
          floatingLabelStyle={styles.floatingLabelStyle}
          floatingLabelFocusStyle={styles.floatingLabelFocusStyle}
          underlineStyle={styles.underlineStyle}
          underlineFocusStyle={styles.underlineFocusStyle}
          component={InputTextField}
        />
        <br />
        <Field
          id="firstname"
          name="firstname"
          floatingLabelText="ΟΝΟΜΑ"
          floatingLabelStyle={styles.floatingLabelStyle}
          floatingLabelFocusStyle={styles.floatingLabelFocusStyle}
          underlineStyle={styles.underlineStyle}
          underlineFocusStyle={styles.underlineFocusStyle}
          component={InputTextField}
        />
        <br />
        <Field
          id="companyName"
          name="companyName"
          floatingLabelText="ΟΝΟΜΑ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑΣ"
          floatingLabelStyle={styles.floatingLabelStyle}
          floatingLabelFocusStyle={styles.floatingLabelFocusStyle}
          underlineStyle={styles.underlineStyle}
          underlineFocusStyle={styles.underlineFocusStyle}
          component={InputTextField}
        />
        <br />
        <Field
          id="mobile"
          name="mobile"
          floatingLabelText="ΚΙΝΗΤΟ"
          floatingLabelStyle={styles.floatingLabelStyle}
          floatingLabelFocusStyle={styles.floatingLabelFocusStyle}
          underlineStyle={styles.underlineStyle}
          underlineFocusStyle={styles.underlineFocusStyle}
          component={InputTextField}
        />
        <br />
        <Field
          id="generatorSN"
          name="generatorSN"
          floatingLabelText="GENERATOR SN"
          floatingLabelStyle={styles.floatingLabelStyle}
          floatingLabelFocusStyle={styles.floatingLabelFocusStyle}
          underlineStyle={styles.underlineStyle}
          underlineFocusStyle={styles.underlineFocusStyle}
          component={InputTextField}
        />
        <br />
      </React.Fragment>
)

export default CustomerSearch
```

But I'm getting an error that:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `CustomerSearch`.

Why is that happening? I used a div and it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: React Fragments were introduced in `v16.2.0`, not in `16.0.2`. In fact, there isn't any `16.0.2` release. Is it a typo?

Comment: Sorry i meant 16.2.0

Comment: I tried it..still the same error

Comment: I've checked that when i run npm update it is saying that react and react dom have unmet peer dependencies

Comment: Can you please show the code of `CustomerSearch` component?

Comment: The error message mentions `CustomerSearch`, but you're showing us `Hello` - please include the code where the error is actually occurring.

Comment: Hello is an example...CustomerSearch is the actual component.

Comment: it might be a loader problem - just because you updated React doesn't mean the changes in jsx involved to make this happen are present - be sure to upgrade all dependencies in the build chain and try again - the code you pasted doesn't look wrong so its time to look elsewhere.

Comment: It might be something with the dependencies i agree

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the dependencies. 
I ran npm install npm@latest -g
And my problem was fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you didn't update `react-dom` to the latest version